# How to get the input text from the TextField in an alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

This question has been asked before, in:[Get input value from TextField in iOS alert in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567413/how-to-get-input-value-from-textfield-in-alert). However, does somebody have the code in the Objective-C language?

Thanks in advance!

What I've gotten so far:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Adding A Row"
    message:@"Enter A Number"
    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"";
}];

UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];

UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
//Do some action here
}];

[alert addAction:cancel];
[alert addAction:ok];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: That should not be too hard to translate. What part of the Objective-C code do you have so far? Have you created an `UIAlertController` already? Have you added a textfield?

Comment: I have already add a textfield. Having trouble with :    //3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK. 
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
    println("Text field: \(textField.text)")
}))

Comment: Okay, please show the code that you have already got and where you think you need help, will be happy to provide some if you show the current code of yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the same logic as in `Swift`: write `alert.textFields[0].text` inside the action handler in the following way:

```
UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    NSString *input = alert.textFields[0].text;
    NSLog(@"input was '%@'", input);
}];
```

Which in my test prints

> input was '1234'

Comment: It worked! Thank you! :D